# OpenGL Android Translate object on y Axis 2D

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opengl-es

I cannot seem to get my object to move on the y axis, it just stays at its current location.

To my current knowledge I know to use

```
Matrix.translateM()
```

However it does not seem to work and I am not sure what step I am missing.

In my renderer the OnDrawFrame Method is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    // Clear the rendering surface.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Apply transformation, start with translation

    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);
    // Create a rotation transformation for the triangle
    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
    float mAngle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);



    Matrix.orthoM(mMatrix, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);

    // Combine Rotation and Translation matrices
    mTempMatrix = mModelMatrix.clone();
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

    // Combine the model matrix with the projection and camera view
    mTempMatrix = mMVPMatrix.clone();
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.orthoM(mMatrix, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
   mCircle.draw(mMatrix);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mCircle.mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mCircle.mModelMatrix, 0, 50.5f, 5.7f, 5.7f);

    //mTriangle.draw(mMatrix);

}
```

My Circle class is as follows

```
public class Circle{
public float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];
public FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
public float vertices[] = new float[364 * 3];
float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };
public float ofset = 0;
private final String vertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private final int mProgram;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float triangleCoords[] = {
        // in counterclockwise order:
        0.0f,  0.622008459f, 0.0f,   // top
        -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
        0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f    // bottom right
};
private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    public Circle(){
        vertices[0] = 0;
        vertices[1] = 0;
        vertices[2] = 0;

        for(int i =1; i < 364; i++){
            vertices[(i * 3)+ 0] = (float) (0.1 * Math.cos((3.14/180) * (float)i )+ofset);

            vertices[(i * 3)+ 1] = (float) (0.059 * Math.sin((3.14/180) * (float)i )+ofset);
            vertices[(i * 3)+ 2] = 0;
        }
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                vertices.length * 4);
        // use the device hardware's native byte order
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
        int vertexShader = ImpulseRushRenderer.loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = ImpulseRushRenderer.loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables
    }

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");


    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

    GLES30.glDrawArrays(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 364);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

}

}
```

I can't seem to find a step by step guide for getting a translation to work so I am assuming I am missing something important.I have gotten Rotate to work before but I am having no luck trying to get Translation to work.

Comment: You are using a translate on a matrix that is not used at all. Or is there some relation between the mCircle.mModelMatrix and the mModelMatrix in the on draw method?

Comment: No, I created 1 in both, I am a little hazy on using the mModelMatrix for translation.

Comment: So if the matrix that you are translating is not even used you can not expect to see any changes when translating it.

Comment: Any chance you could give an example of how to use this correctly in an answer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry just a bit confused,

Comment: Just keep to one single model matrix in your case. Either only use the one from the circle or the one from the draw method in all the calls.

Comment: Any chance you can post an example so I can give you a check? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be consistent with your matrices and know when to use which. In the code you posted you actually translated the matrix that is not in use at all so no change was made.

Usually an MVP matrix system is used which means a product of 3 matrices which are Model, View and Projection. Each of these represents a part of the transformation of the drawn object and until you get to some optimizations you are best to use all 3 of them both in your application and in the shaders. For some systems such as lighting you will need to separate them for the shader anyway.

So a model matrix is the one that represents the model in the scene. An identity should be used so it is placed in the center with no rotations or scale. Then modify it to change the model position in the scene such as translating it. It makes sense for each model to have its own model matrix (but not projection and view).

A view matrix represents the user or camera position in the scene. In most cases you will use look-at procedure to give the position, the location you are looking toward and the up vector. In most cases you will have only one of these but there may be more in cases such as split screen.

A projection matrix is used to define the coordinates system and or projection of your scene. The most common here is to use `ortho` or `frustum`. They are very similar to look at and basically one is used for 2D and another for 3D. This matrix is used closely with "view" matrix.

So if you use all 3 of them then it gets pretty simple. Once the view is generated or the view frame changes you will need to setup the projection matrix. The vie matrix must change when you want to look around or move around the scene. And the model matrix should be set for every draw call. Do make sure all of them are set at least to identity from the beginning or none of the operations will work on them.

I hope this clears a few things.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. I am using mmatrix in the circle class. So when i use mcircle.mModelMatrix isnt that using it? In the renderer classes method draw i use them and tell it toove x and y coordinates. So i am bit confused still what is wrong with the way its implemented? From your explanations i know somehow in need to have the coordinates for where the object is.

Comment: No, this line: "GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);" is the one that sets the matrix and uses the mvpMatrix which is received as a method parameter and is not modified by the actual matrix held by the circle.

Comment: Alright. So there i would use mCirvle.mModelMatrix. so now that is for the circle. So now for it to be moved I need to set the mModelMatrix to the circles current position before applying the translation? Thanks again

Comment: You always need a product of all 3 matrices as described above. The MVP can be construed at any time you have all of the information. In your case that seems to be in the beginning which may be what is confusing you. A model matrix should be defined by the model which is the circle and the model matrix is what defines the model position and orientation in the scene. So for instance you do not need a circle to hold the matrix at all, it might just have the position from which you can construct the model matrix by translating the identity in your draw method.

Comment: You could even discard the model matrix overall in your case and add a new uniform which is a translation vector for the circle position. Then in the vertex shader you may simply sum the position attribute with the translation vector. I am not suggesting you should do that as it will make a development harder when you will try to add some rotations but it is something to keep in mind that is possible and maybe help you towards the understanding on how this all works.